# Sharepoint 2013 flowchart workflow custom code

Tags: visual-studio-2013, workflow, sharepoint-2013, workflow-foundation-4, custom-code

I'am SharePoint 2013 beginner and i have a project where i need to create a workflow (With Visual Studio), so i started my workflow as flowchart workflow then at some point i needed to write custom code (like to get something from DB) but couldn't find anyway to do that (i can't call the class's functions), whereas in 2010's sequential workflow the wf already has a code behind class.

So my question is: Is there anyway i could call custom code like in sequential workflows !?

Note: I already added a class and tried to use "InvokeMethod" with it, but couldn't reach the class's functions.

Answer (score -1):

Use HttpSend-activity. Microsoft is forcing us to write restful endpoints. And it is a good thing. I would go as far that we should avoid deploying services on SharePoint server. Microsoft is pretty clear here.

1) Get a server
2) Deploy wcf-service that uses the sharepoint client object model to get stuff done 
3) Use httpsend-activity

HttpSend
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn532193.aspx